# pyspark: referencing columns by dataframe during a join

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join two pyspark dataframes like this

```
joined = df.join(df1,on=["date"],how='left').select([col('df.'+xx) for xx in df.columns] + [col('df1.daily_net_payment_sum'),col('df1.daily_net_payment_avg')])
```

But it results in

```
An error was encountered:
"cannot resolve '`df.cust_no`' given input columns:
```

Seems to me like I am unable to reference column by their dataframe/table name. Using spark 2.4.7

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: Can you post the schema of the two DFs please? Or the entire stack trace? Or rhe show statements on both DFs. This question doesn't tells anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by first creating [aliases](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.alias.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.alias) for each dataset.

```py
df = df.alias("df")
df1 = df1.alias("df1")
joined = df.join(df1,on=["date"],how='left').select([col('df.'+xx) for xx in df.columns] + [col('df1.daily_net_payment_sum'),col('df1.daily_net_payment_avg')])
```

Comment: Column names should be available even without aliases I guess

Comment: I ran a quick test to create a similar join with another schema before posting. Column names are not available when prefixed with `df` or `df1` unless spark is made aware of the alias for each daraframe. The op is asking how to reference daraframes using these aliases as prefixes.

Comment: @ggordon Thank you! That worked. Surprising that it doesn't recognize it without the aliases.